# How can I only update some specific tensors in network with pytorch?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

For instance, I want to only update all cnn weights in Resnet in the first 10 epochs and freeze the others.
And from 11th epoch, I wanna change to update the whole model.
How can I achieve the goal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the learning rate (and some other meta-parameters) per parameters group. You only need to group your parameters according to your needs.
For example, setting different learning rate for conv layers:

```
import torch
import itertools
from torch import nn

conv_params = itertools.chain.from_iterable([m.parameters() for m in model.children()
                                             if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d)])
other_params = itertools.chain.from_iterable([m.parameters() for m in model.children()
                                              if not isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d)]) 
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD([{'params': other_params},
                             {'params': conv_params, 'lr': 0}],  # set init lr to 0
                            lr=lr_for_model)
```

You can later access the optimizer `param_groups` and modify the learning rate.

See [per-parameter options](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#per-parameter-options) for more information.

Comment: This has sense if you consider the optimizers are made to deal with param groups.

Answer (score 0):

very straightforward, as PYTORCH recreate the computational graph on the fly.

```
for p in resnet.parameters():
    p.requires_grad = False # this will freeze the module from training suppose that resnet is one of your module
```

if you have multiple modules, simply loop over it. then after 10 epoch, you simply call

```
for p in network.parameters():
    p.requires_grad = True # suppose your whole network is the 'network' module
```